# Dojo charting: How to add labels from datastore to my Axis?

Tags: dojox.charting, dojo

I am still a newbie in dojo and javascript so this may be trivial.
I have created a "dojox.charting.Chart2D"-chart.
I get the data from a datastore (ItemFileReadStore) and can successfully display them in my DataSeries.
I can also create my x a y Axis but the only contain simple numbers.
What i need is to add to my x-Axis the text values from one field in my store.
I found that this could be done with "labelFunc: function (n) {}" but i simply can't get it to read the data from my store.

My store data looks like this:

```
{ identifier: "UniqueId"  , items: [
{"UniqueId":1, "VisitDate":"2012-02-21T00:00:00", "VisitsTotal":407, "Visits10":71, "Visits15":6},
{"UniqueId":2, "VisitDate":"2012-02-20T00:00:00", "VisitsTotal":508, "Visits10":80, "Visits15":10},
...
```

My code is like this:

```
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ url: './../Data/MyJSONData.aspx' });
chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("simplechart1");  
chart1.addAxis("x", {fixUpper: "major",fixLower: "minor",title: 'Datum',
labelFunc: function (n) {
// HOW DO I GET THE VALUES 'VisitDate' FROM MY STORE ???
}});

chart1.addSeries('VisitsTotal',
new dojox.charting.DataSeries(store, { query: { Visits10: "*"} }, "Visits10"),
{ stroke: 'red', fill: 'pink' }
);

chart1.addSeries('Visits10',
new dojox.charting.DataSeries(store, { query: { Visits10: "*"} }, "Visits10"),
{ stroke: 'red', fill: 'pink' }
);
...
```

I already tried any combination but i really am missing some basics, on how to read from the store and also how to set my own text values (labels) to my X-Axis.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add (labels) to X-Axis.**

```
chart1.addAxis("x", { labels: [{value: 1, text: "Jan"}, {value: 2, text: "Feb"},
                         {value: 3, text: "Mar"}, {value: 4, text: "Apr"},
                         {value: 5, text: "May"}, {value: 6, text: "Jun"},
                         {value: 7, text: "Jul"}]
    });
```

Or see in [My jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/FHnwd/)

**Read data from the store**

```
store.fetch( { query: {},  
               onItem: function(item) {
                  console.log(store.getValue( item, 'VisitDate' ) );
               }
});
```

See more at [Dojo Livedoc](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore#query-syntax) or [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367386/how-do-i-retrieve-values-from-dojo-data-itemfilereadstore)